# How to run a program installed on the Windows partition with Wine?

Tags: dual-boot, wine

I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu (but rarely ever use windows, just in case there is something I need Windows for) and I already have `The Sims 3` installed on my Windows partition. I was just wondering (since I know you can access that partition from Ubuntu),  if I could use Wine to run `The Sims 3` from that partition,

1. so that I don't have to install it a second time and could save space,
2. Because there really is no sense in installing it twice,

If it is possible could someone tell me how to do this? I also noticed in the description of wine that you could run it (if you dual boot) using the actual windows files, could someone also tell me how to do that and if it would be a good idea?

Comment: That is not possible to my knowledge. You need to install sims3 with your wine installer. 1. sure it saves space. 2. and how does wine know the settings it needs for a game to run.  I will be glad to be proven wrong but ... no I do not think this is possible.

Comment: You could try monitoring what registry entries does the sims executable read with SysInternals' ProcessMonitor, export them and import them into Wine's registry and then try to run the program, but I think that you'll lose more time with trying to do that than with installing the game the second time.

Answer (score 22):

Some applications *can* be copied from Windows to Wine and still work, but **don't try this** unless you like tinkering under the hood of your car while it's running.

Wine is **not** designed to interact with an existing Windows installation. If you have any data you need from a Windows installation, browse your Windows filesystems in your normal file manager and copy the data to another location.

> **WARNING:** Do ***not*** try to configure Wine to point to your actual
> Windows C:\ drive.
> **This will break Windows** and require a Windows
> reinstall.
>
> We have tried to make this hard to do, so you probably cannot do it by
> accident.
>
> If you do manage this, Wine may or may not continue to operate, but
> your Windows install will be **100% dead** due to critical parts of it
> being overwritten.
> The only way to fix Windows after this has happened
> is to reinstall it.

*[Source](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#I_have_lots_of_applications_already_installed_in_Windows._How_do_I_run_them_in_Wine.3F)*

Comment: Can you please copy a bit from that into the answer? Links tend to rot.

Comment: You're right.. I was lazy. Done!

Comment: here have some rep :+

Comment: No problem sir :) accepting the answer is praise enough @sircharlo

Comment: thanks for the imput, i ended up searching around and finding similar answers (i had forgotten about this form) i just switched back to windows for a bit

Answer (score -1):

If your intent is to run a program that is already installed outside of Wine's C partition:
then simply run `winecfg`
in appeared window choose the drives tab
and add the partition containing the program to the list in front of you
then it can be opened with Wine either by "open with wine" or by executing `wine drive_letter/path_to_program` where drive_letter is the same letter chosen for the partition in winecfg